# navision testing environment

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I have a long experience in programming C#. I have used navision 2009 years ago as an end user. Now I would like to refresh my programming skill by starting coding with Navision 2009 or Navision 2013.

From what I have seen I need the development toolkit and a fresh install on Navision. However as far as I have understood there is no trial for navision for testing and developing. Microsoft Navision site seems to require to be a partner for accessing the downloading part of the nav site.

Obviously I do not want to pay a fully Navision environment neither becoming a partner. So any suggestions? Is there any trial version of navision that I can download for testing the C/AL programming basics?

Paolo

Answer (score 1):

You can try programming a little bit with demo CRONUS licence that comes with NAV but is very limited.

You can modify the Customer table (Table 18) and add field numbers 99990 to 99999 to the Customer table. 
You can modify the Customer Card form (Form 21) and the Customer List form (Form 22), and you can create two new forms that have the object IDs 99998 and 99999.
The standard report Customer List (Report 101) can be modified, and you can create a new report that has object ID 99999. There is no access to dataport objects.

More details here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/857936